# how to install chai plugin to be used by Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress, chai

I use Cypress v10 with typescript. I'd like to add [chai-subset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-subset) plugin. I've added npm package already.

How should I configure Cypress to see the plugin? Will it be then also available for code completion in Visual Studio Code ?

Answer (score 4):

The steps given on the npm page are as follows, BUT for Cypress you should omit the first line `require('chai')` because Cypress has added chai globally and modified it to allow the `.should()` command to use it.

Add it to the `/support/e2e.js` file.

```js
// var chai = require('chai');                // NOT THIS LINE
var chaiSubset = require('chai-subset');
chai.use(chaiSubset);
```

Usage:

```js
cy.get(...)
  .should('containSubset', {
    a: 'b',
    e: {
        baz: {
            qux: 'quux'
        }
    }
  })
```